# Smartgit has problems to push/pull code to Synology nas, but GitX and other software can

Tags: git, ssh, smartgit, synology

well it's what the subject says.

I have a Synology NAS with the Git package installed. I have a user with git-shell:ssh access, **not full ssh access**.

With GitX and SourceTree I can perform the regular actions (commit, push, pull, ...), however with Smartgit I can do only local actions (commit) but no remote actions such as push, pull, clone. It continuously asks for login password, even if I do nothing.

Also, if I enter the password, it complains about read permissions.

I've been able to do all actions (commit, push, pull and clone) with other software as GitX, SourceTree and in a terminal window.

Why is Smartgit having so many problems? IT seems to need full ssh access to the server, why should it need this access?

Any clues?

Also, if you have experience with other **FREE** git clients you like, let me know.

Comment: Did you try to change to **System SSH client** in SmartGit's Preferences, section **Authentication**?

Comment: @mstrap it is the default option. I have selected the option "use system SSH client". The other option is "Use SmartGit as SSH client".

Comment: And neither option works?

Comment: no. :/   It is really weird. I manage to do Git basic things via Terminal and GitX over a git restricted  ssh connection. It seems as if Smartgit tries to have a regular shell when connecting to the server via SSH.